# Is data.table::hour() unstable?

Tags: r, data.table, hour

I was trying to calculate the hour of some timestamps and I noticed some very strange results: It looks like there is some input that breaks the function completely (not only does it produce 0 as a result, but it breaks vectorization and forces 0 on every item).

Here is a reproducable example:

```
library(data.table)
someTimestamps = c("2014-03-30 03:08:07", 
                   "2014-03-30 09:08:07", 
                   "2014-03-31 03:08:07", # <-- problematic input
                   "2014-03-31 09:08:07",
                   "2014-04-01 03:08:07",
                   "2014-04-01 09:08:07")

for (i in 1:6) print(hour(someTimestamps[i]))

# prints [1] 3
#        [1] 9
#        [1] 0
#        [1] 9
#        [1] 3
#        [1] 9

print(hour(someTimestamps))  # prints [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0
print(hour(someTimestamps[c(1:2, 4:6)]))  # prints [1] 3 9 9 3 9
```

I also noticed that when `hour()` breaks `minute()` breaks as well.

I do not know how to explain this. Is there some explanation? It's surely a bug, right?
I tried to experiment by changing the year, it seems to work fine.

I assume a workaround would be to use some other date function or work with regex, but it feels like I've stumbled upon something potentially dangerous.

Comment: It must be related to a timezone, I see no problem with the output.

Comment: It works just fine for me, which means this is an issue with daylight saving time and depends on your locale. This datetime probably does not exist in your time zone.

Comment: For character input, `hour` is just a wrapper for `as.POSIXlt(x)$hour`.

Comment: I don't think  it's a timezone issue. It doesn't explain why the function works on all the other timestamps and fails on this one specifically. However, the fact that people cannot seem to reproduce it COULD be related to a timezone issue. ("2014-03-31 03:08:07") might be interpretted differently?

Comment: I might have expected an issue on `03-30`, though, due to daylight savings in 2014 (in Greece, for example) on March 30 at 3am local. Not sure why `03-31` is behaving badly for you, though I don't see it. Check `Sys.timezone()` and `attr(someTimestamps, "tzone")` to help identify what might be going on; realize you can always _force_ the TZ with `attr(., "tzone") <- "Europe/Athens"` (continuing my Greece example).

Comment: Or try `TZ=UTC R` and see if you can reproduce problem then. Nice to see you are in Greek tz @r2evans :)

Comment: @jangorecki I consider myself more tz-agnostic, not assuming everybody is in `"US/*"` :-). No, though, I'm not in Greece, though I've thoroughly enjoyed my visits there.

Comment: What is your output? Cannot reproduce an error.

Comment: @feinmann I edited the question to display what the results are.

Comment: What is the data.table version? Did you also try data.table::hour() to ensure, that the data.table-function is called?

Comment: @feinmann data.table version is 1.14.2. Yes, I am 100% certain that it is data.table::hour() that is called. It's shocking that no one else can reproduce the issue!

Comment: Could you give us the output of `lubridate::now()`? To be honest, I believe there is a problem with your installation, but maybe it is indeed related to your TZ?

Comment: And: Is `as.POSIXlt("2014-03-31 03:08:07")$hour` really `0` on your system?

Comment: @feinmann `lubridate::now()` returns `"2022-10-03 09:25:01 +03"`, `as.POSIXlt("2014-03-31 03:08:07")$hour` indeed returns `0`.

Comment: And what about `as.POSIXlt("2014-03-31 03:08:07 +03")$hour` ... Sorry, I have no clue... but your return of lubridate::now( ) is also not familiar to me.

Comment: `as.POSIXlt("2014-03-31 03:08:07 +03")$hour` returns `0`. Don't worry, I admire your persistence! :)